# how can I do parallel reduction approach to combine the partial sums in c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, reduction

I have to do partial sums using parallel reduction approach in C. but I doesn't have any idea about it. So, I need guidance of Community to achieve this.

**What I need to achieve:** for example,  computational thread, then in first reduction step add two element in array, thread 4 should wait for thread 0 done, same as thread 5 has to wait for thread 1 done, thread 6 waits for thread 2 & thread 7 should waits for thread 3 done .

now in second step, , thread 6 waits for thread 4 finished, and thread 7 waits for thread 5 finished. , thread 6 waits for thread 4 finished, and thread 7 waits for thread 5 finished.

In the third step, thread 7 waits for thread 6 done. then need to print whole array

Please help me, give me a guidance to achieve this one.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Is your difficulty in computing which other thread a given thread should wait on, or something else?

Comment: I'm confused about how to manage computing thread a given thread should wait. 2^r-i, where r = log(m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm confused about how to manage computing thread a given thread should wait. `2^r-i`, where `r = log(m)`.

There are at least two easy ways to do that:

- save all thread-ids in a global `pthread_t ptid[N];` array.
- save all thread-ids in a local `pthread_t ptid[N];` array, and pass the address of that array into each thread via the thread argument.

Example pseudo-code for the latter (error handling omitted for clarity):

```
struct Arg {
  pthread_t *ptid;  // Address of ptid[N].
  int idx;          // Index of this thread.
};

void *partial_sum(void *p)
{
  struct Arg *arg = (struct Arg *)p;

  int sum = 0;
  ... // Compute my portion of the partial sum.
  
  int other_thread_idx = ...;  // Compute index of the other thread
                               // this thread should join, -1 if none.
  if (other_thread_idx >= 0) {
    int other_sum;

    // Get the result from other thread.
    pthread_join(arg->ptid[other_thread_idx], (void*) &other_sum);
    printf("Thread %d joined thread %d which returned sum %d\n",
           arg->idx, other_thread_idx, other_sum);
    sum += other_sum;
  }
  printf("Thread %d, sum: %d\n", arg->idx, sum);
  return (void*) sum;
}

int main()
{
  struct Arg args[N];
  pthread_t ptid[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    struct Arg* arg = &args[i];
    arg->idx = i;
    arg->ptid = &ptid[0];
    pthread_create(&ptid[i], NULL, partial_sum, arg);
  }

  // Get the final result.
  int sum;

  // Note: joining only the last thread -- all others have been joined
  // already.
  pthread_join(ptid[N - 1], (void*) &sum);

  printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think OpenMP is more suitable for your question. It support C and don't need to change too much on your code. Following solution modified based on the Intel document. And works well on Ubuntu 22.04 with gcc 11.

```
// parallel_reduction.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint32_t i = 0, n=0xfffffff;
    float *array, total=0.0f;

    array = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        total += array[i];
    }

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile the code with gcc (or g++ if you're using C++), and benchmark on the performance.

```
gcc -fopenmp parallel_reduction.c -o pr
time ./pr

real    0m0.078s
user    0m2.806s
sys     0m5.854s
```

OpenMP can utilize all of your CPU cores by default, and this behavior can be changed by environment variable.

```
time OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./pr
```

This code improve more than 10x performance on my side. For your reference.

The Intel oneTBB library also include "parallel_reduce" algorithm. But it only support C++, and need more modification on your code. The advantage is it's a library, and don't need special support from compiler.

**[Reference]**

oneTBB: [parallel_reduce](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/algorithms/functions/parallel_reduce_func.html)

OpenMP: [OpenMP Reduction Operations](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/advisor-user-guide/top/model-threading-designs/add-parallelism-to-your-program/replace-annotations-with-openmp-code/openmp-reduction-operations.html)

Comment: Thank you for responding to me. can you put sample source code in answer related to my question?

Comment: There're sample code in the document.

Comment: ya I have seen it. but how can I do thread 4 waits for thread 0 done, thread 5 wait for thread 1 etc.... how to I achieve this one?

Comment: AFAIK, with OpenMP, you cannot wait for specific threads. OpenMP focus on data dependencies. For specific thread sync, you can use wait conditions. This is generally a bug-prone low-level approach, so certainly not a good idea. What about doing a naive barrier? Or a thread reduction with the reduction clause on a parallel directive.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the "wait", that's what the threading library does for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as an explanation of how to use those libraries, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. Note that answers containing links are expected to reference/quote the link source so that the answer can stand alone.